# Corrupt Zip file using ZipOutputStream to create DOCX file

Tags: java, android, kotlin, zip, zipoutputstream

I use `ZipOutputStream` to compress the content of a folder into a Zip file. Below is my working code. But it creates corrupt DOCX files. Trying to extract them on macOS fails.

```kotlin
private const val DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 * 4

fun zip(source: String?, destination: String?, contentsOnly: Boolean, compression: Int) {
    try {
        val zipOut = ZipOutputStream(FileOutputStream(destination))
        val srcFile = File(source)

        // Compression Level
        val compressionLevel: Int = when(compression) {
             0 -> Deflater.DEFAULT_COMPRESSION
             1 -> Deflater.NO_COMPRESSION
             2 -> Deflater.BEST_SPEED
             3 -> Deflater.BEST_COMPRESSION
            else -> {
                Deflater.DEFAULT_COMPRESSION
            }
        }

        zipOut.setLevel(compressionLevel)
        zipOut.setMethod(ZipOutputStream.DEFLATED)

        if (contentsOnly && srcFile.isDirectory) {
            for (fileName in srcFile.list()) {
                addToZip("", source + File.separator + fileName, zipOut)
            }
        } else {
            if (source != null) {
                addToZip("", source, zipOut)
            }
        }
        zipOut.flush()
        zipOut.finish()
        zipOut.close()
        println("Successfully created $destination")
    } catch (error: Exception) {
        println("Failed")
    }
}

private fun addToZip(path: String, srcFile: String, zipOut: ZipOutputStream) {
    val file = File(srcFile)
    val filePath = if ("" == path) file.name else path + File.separator + file.name
    if (file.isDirectory) {
        for (fileName in file.list()) {
            addToZip(filePath, srcFile + File.separator + fileName, zipOut)
        }
    } else {
        zipOut.putNextEntry(ZipEntry(filePath))
        val `in` = FileInputStream(srcFile)
        val buffer = ByteArray(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE)
        var len: Int
        while (`in`.read(buffer).also { len = it } != -1) {
            zipOut.write(buffer, 0, len)
        }
    }
}
```

I use the code e.g. to compress the folder **"paragraph"**, which you can find here: https://github.com/stiv-yakovenko/toptal-docx/tree/master/paragraph. The Zip file is generated, I can view the Structure inside Android Studio, but if I try to extract it, I get the message the file is corrupt. Compress other folders, which are not based on OfficeOpenXml (*.docx*, *.xsxl* etc.) works fine.

Comment: `Trying to extract them on macOS fails.` So on an Android device all is ok?

Comment: I see no .docx files in that paragraph folder.

Comment: Sounds like this is not at all a problem with zip (IntelliJ properly opens it and it works for other formats than docx), but with the contents of the zip maybe?

Comment: @blackapps - No, it's an invalid file too. The paragraph folder is the raw folder which needs to be compressed to e.g. test.docx or test.zip (makes no difference) using the "zip" function above. This results in a corrupted file. It could have to do with the fact the paragraph folder owns files without file name and having just a dot ending (see _rels/.rels).

Comment: @broot - No, the raw docx folder structure is definitely valid. I've done this for a desktop app in another programming language and with the same paragraph folder and it works as expected.